# How to check if a variable is an integer or a string?

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7

I have an application that has a couple of commands.
When you type a certain command, you have to type in additional info about something/someone.
Now that info has to be strictly an integer or a string, depending on the situation.

However, whatever you type into Python using raw_input() actually is a string, no matter what, so more specifically, how would I shortly and without try...except see if a variable is made of digits or characters?

Comment: You could do: `"0".isdigit()`. Documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit

Comment: Checking an object's type in Python is a bad idea - it makes Python's dynamic nature less useful. *It's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.*

Comment: Why the aversion to `try`..`except` here? This is *exactly* what you'd use exception handling *for*.

Comment: Mostly because I don't understand try...except...

Comment: isinstance (in answer below) is a good way to go in the case of just needing to know whether the content of a variable is a string or integer. This can happen when a user option can be either.

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64132078/8321339

Answer (score 103, accepted):

In my opinion you have two options:

- Just try to convert it to an `int`, but catch the exception:

  ```
  try:
      value = int(value)
  except ValueError:
      pass  # it was a string, not an int.
  ```

  This is the Ask Forgiveness approach.
- Explicitly test if there are only digits in the string:

  ```
  value.isdigit()
  ```

  [`str.isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) returns `True` only if all characters in the string are digits (`0`-`9`).

  The `unicode` / Python 3 `str` type equivalent is [`unicode.isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#unicode.isdecimal) / [`str.isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal); only Unicode decimals can be converted to integers, as not all digits have an actual integer value ([U+00B2 SUPERSCRIPT 2](http://codepoints.net/U+00B2) is a digit, but not a decimal, for example).

  This is often called the Ask Permission approach, or Look Before You Leap.

The latter will not detect all valid `int()` values, as whitespace and `+` and `-` are also allowed in `int()` values. The first form will happily accept `'  +10  '` as a number, the latter won't.

If your expect that the user *normally* will input an integer, use the first form. It is easier (and faster) to ask for forgiveness rather than for permission in that case.

Comment: The are other options. Better say that those two options are just what you would recommend yourself.

Comment: @android: The other options are overkill for most situations. Yet, quantified it.

Comment: The problem is that I don't really understand try...except, so if you could explain it more thoroughly, that would be great.

Comment: @user2154354: Operations can throw exceptions; these cut through the normal flow of code, they 'fall down' through the stack; functions immediately return, until something 'catches' the exception. The `try:`..`except:` statement does the catching. `int()` can throw a `ValueError` exception, but we specifically catch it again to detect that the string was not convertable to an integer. See the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) for more details.

Comment: @Veedrac: indeed, pointed out now.

Comment: `isdigit()` retunrs `False` for negative numbers

Comment: @Mawg: yes, which is why I was explicit about it only returning true if all characters are digits. `-` is not a digit.

Comment: True. But it only works for positive integers, not all integers :-(

Answer (score 40):

if you want to check what it is:

```
>>>isinstance(1,str)
False
>>>isinstance('stuff',str)
True
>>>isinstance(1,int)
True
>>>isinstance('stuff',int)
False
```

if you want to get ints from raw_input

```
>>>x=raw_input('enter thing:')
enter thing: 3
>>>try: x = int(x)
   except: pass

>>>isinstance(x,int)
True
```

Comment: Use basestring instead of str, to catch unicode, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979004/what-is-the-difference-between-isinstanceaaa-basestring-and-isinstanceaaa

Comment: That's perfect for me, it works for positive and negative numbers ... cool, thanks

Comment: one liner: `print(isinstance('stuff',int))`

Answer (score 8):

The [`isdigit` method of the `str` type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) returns `True` iff the given string is nothing but one or more digits.  If it's not, you know the string should be treated as just a string.

Comment: isdigit() retunrs False for negative numbers

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your definition of shortly, you could use one of the following options:

- `try: int(your_input); except ValueError: # ...`
- [`your_input.isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)
- use a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586346/python-regex-for-integer)
- use [`parse`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) which is kind of the opposite of `format`

Answer (score 1):

Don't check. Go ahead and assume that it is the right input, and catch an exception if it isn't.

```
intresult = None
while intresult is None:
    input = raw_input()
    try: intresult = int(input)
    except ValueError: pass
```