# How to check if a number is a number when it is a 'string'?

Tags: python, types, integer

This is a part of a larger program. Here is what I am trying to do.

1. Pass a sentence to the scan method.
2. Have the sentence contain numbers.
3. Split the sentence into it's different terms.
4. append to a list a tuple, the first expression in the tuple being the type of thing that the word or sentence element fits into, the second being the word or number.

Here is what I am trying:

```
def scan(self, sentence):
    self.term = []

    for word in sentence.split():
        if word in direction:
            self.term.append(('direction', word))
        elif word in verbs:
            self.term.append(('verb', word))
        elif word in stop:
            self.term.append(('stop', word))
        elif word in nouns:
            self.term.append(('noun', word))
        elif type(int(word)) == 'int':
            self.term.append(('number', int(word)))
        else:
            self.term.append(('error', word))

    return self.term



print lexicon.scan('12 1234')
```

This is a method in a class, the print statement is outside. The part I am concerned with and having trouble with is this:

```
elif type(int(word)) == int:
    self.term.append(('number', int(word)))
```

It should work for any natural number [1, infinity)

Edit:
I run into a problem when I try to scan('ASDFASDFASDF')

Comment: what are you doing exactly? type(int(word)) == int ??? you convert it to int then check if it's int?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/python-how-to-check-if-input-is-a-number-given-that-input-always-returns-stri of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488278/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-a-string of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-python of ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you only need positive integers, then try `elif word.isdigit():` (note that this will also accept "0").

Comment: You could do `elif word.isdigit() and word != '0':` to filter out zero.

Comment: Possibly: `elif word.ltrim('0').isdigit()`

Comment: `elif word.isdigit() and int(word) > 0:`

Comment: I'd stick with string-style methods during the 'if' test, such as Jon Clements's suggestion of lstrip, and try to do the int() conversion only once in the elif body once we know we want this value as a positive integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if word.lstrip('0').isdigit(): 
    #append
```

Using the `.lstrip('0')` will remove leading 0's and cause strings such as `'0'` and `'000'` to not pass the check.  Simply doing `if word.isdigit() and word !='0'` will not exclude `'00'` or any other string that is just multiple `'0'`s

You could also use a `try`/`except`/`else` to see if it is an `int` and respond accordingly

```
try:
    int(s)
except ValueError:
    print s, 'is not an int'
else:
    print s, 'is an int'
```

Comment: `s` is a string, so you mean "and s != '0'".

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I meant `int(s)` actually, but yeah my mistake thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could apply `int` to `word` and catch a `ValueError` if it's not a number.

Comment: Do an `except ValueError:` then what?