# How to check if regex matches only number?

Tags: python, regex

There are many expressions to match with number, something like `\d` , `1[0-9][0-9]`, `\d{4}`,...
But how to check if the expression matches only number?

For example, `\d` matches 0 to9, so the expression is **true** as "matches only number".

Another example, `1[0-9a-z]` matches number like 10, but also matches 1s which is not number. So **false** as "matches only number".

It is difficult to describe what "number" is, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246077/matching-numbers-with-regular-expressions-only-digits-and-commas/4247184%234247184), so I would like to restrict it just an integer.

My question doesn't mean that I want an expression which matches integer, but kind of reverse regex to check expression itself. Thanks to read! :)

Comment: Are you trying to programmatically determine using one regex whether another regex could ever match any string that is not just integers? Except for trivial cases where there is only `\d` or `[0-9]` and multipliers, this is *extremely difficult*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586346/python-regex-for-integer

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about? Are you talking about integers and decimals?

Comment: you can either make a new regex based off from what you know that validates a regex or test that regex by throwing some dummy data and if-else to catch result...

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes right, just not necessary to use one regex to achieve that if it's possible.

Comment: @Craftein at first I tried your solution, but if you choose 100 for dummy data, and given expression is '2[0-9]', the test won't pass.. even '2[0-9]' must match number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to check - given some regular expression *r* - if *r* might match anything which is not a number. In that sense, the empty regex `$^` (matching nothing) would pass the test, since it matches nothing (and hence no non-number). `1[0-9][0-9a-z]`, however, matches `10s`, which is not a number, hence the test fails.

That is not possible with Python's regex facilities. You would need a regex language which supports intersection (&), complement (~), and test for non-emptiness (e.g., through *generation* of a matching word). Then, if *r* is your regex, you would need to check if

```
`r & ~(0|[1-9][0-9]*)`
```

is non-empty.

Intersection and complement are computationally expensive, but there are some regex libraries that support them. An example (Java) which I know of is the [BRICS automaton/regex library](http://www.brics.dk/automaton).

This could be realized as follows (assuming you're adhering to the BRICS regex syntax):

```
// Checks if `re` might match a non-number, and returns an example; otherwise, null is returned
public String matchesNonNumber(String re) {
  // construct regex like above
  RegExp bricsRe = new RegExp("(" + re + ") & ~(0|[1-9][0-9]*)", RegExp.INTERSECTION | RegExp.COMPLEMENT);
  Automaton a = bricsRe.toAutomaton();
  return a.getShortestExample(true); // returns shortest accepted string, or null if no string is accepted
}
```

See the JavaDoc of the [RegExp](http://www.brics.dk/automaton/doc/dk/brics/automaton/RegExp.html) and [Automaton](http://www.brics.dk/automaton/doc/dk/brics/automaton/Automaton.html) classes. This is not an example matching the python tag of the question, but the problem you want to solve also is not inherently language-specific.

Comment: It's not often that you find yourself hoping that the question was up to the quality of the answer (and not the other way around).  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, That's what I wanted to know :)